# The last item in my recyclerview is being cut off does anyone know why?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, coordinator-layout

This is my layout XML file, I have a pull to refresh, `recyclerview` and a coordinator layout, I inflate my items into this `recyclerview`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivitys.ViewPager.Fragments.Home">
<com.yalantis.phoenix.PullToRefreshView
    android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_dashboard_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</com.yalantis.phoenix.PullToRefreshView>
```

Comment: What does cut off means?

Comment: it does not show the full last item, only part of it

Comment: Please add some screenshots and the code also.

Answer (score 0):

update your recyclerview dependency to **latest version** in build.gradle file
then use **"wrap_content"** as height for recyclerview in your xml file